# tensorboard sidebar size problem for log names

Tags: tensorboard

As seen in the screenshot below the name of my logs doesn't span to the whole sidebar section and I see a large blank space to the right (red arrows). If the name of my log is long, it will make it hard to compare with other logs especially if I have a lot of logs.

Browsers: Chrome (Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)) / Firefox (70.0.1 (64-bit))

[image: Screenshot from 2019-11-11 13-22-55]

Answer (score 0):

Updating to newer tensorboard (2.0.1) fixes this!

```
pip uninstall tensorboard
pip install tensorboard
```